# Error in Navigation drawer/error with Nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I programmed a quiz with 3 Activities: 1 = QuizActivity, 2= Menu2 and 3= Menu3.  Activity 1 and 2 are working very fine. The problem is in Menu3. There is one code of line which is creating a Nullpoiner excption: **void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference** when I delete this line I can start (by clicking the about item on the Navigation drawer(leads to Menu3 activity))  the menu3 activity. The only problem is when i leave out this line the "Burger icon" (you can see it on the picture) is not there anymore. When i leave the code of line I can`t navigate to Menu3 because when I do that the app force closes. How can i solve this problem?

[image: this part is not appearing]

Menu3 java:

```
       package amapps.impossiblequiz;



import static amapps.impossiblequiz.R.id.nv3;

public class Menu3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout3;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu3);



    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerLayout3 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout3);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout3, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout3.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv3);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_home3):
                    Intent accountActivity3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity3);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}


@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

}

Menu3 XML:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Menu3"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout3">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="215dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu3"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv3"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tint_color_selector2">




</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Menu2 XML:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Menu2"
         android:id="@+id/drawerLayout2"
         android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#f60"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Your score is:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FFAB00"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Highest score:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Restart Quiz!"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="Stats: play and get trophies!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />





        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statsTrophy"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/statsoftrophy"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Info"
            android:alpha="0.30"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_trophy"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_trophy"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:alpha="0.30"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trophy2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/statsTrophy"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/statsTrophy"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy3"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_trophy"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:alpha="0.30"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trophy3" />


    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu2"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv2"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tint_color_selector2">




</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change toogle initialization. May be it helps you.

```
mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout3, mToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
```

**Edit 1**

I figured out your problem. When you call
getSupportActionBar you will get actionBar you recently set. So,that means your toolbar is null. Check that your toolbar id is correct.

P.S. Also, you can simply call

```
ActionBar actionBar = setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

because `setSupportActionBar()` returns ActionBar

**Edit 2**

You don't have a toolbar in your xml file. Add it.

Comment: Still same problem: void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean) null exception

Comment: does not work either, its very strange because I a have the sam code for menu2 there i can switch to QuizActivity (Main activity) with no problems...  i think there is something with the action bar (I set up in styles app theme: ....no actionbar...

Comment: @Alan I rewrote answer, check it (check that toolbar id is correct and that it exists in your menu3 layout)

Comment: I already done that.. doesn`t work (the edit one) It says required android.app.action bar but found void

Comment: @Alan is the id correct and toolbar exists in xml file?

Comment: I updated the question.. I think so can you check it? I think that the code is correct...

Comment: I updated my question again now you can find menu2 xml, there is also no toolbar in it and it works... So how can I add a  toolbar to Menu3 XML.. I am beginner so...

Comment: @Alan you said that you set  NoActionBar theme. It means there is no toolbar in your menu3 acitvity by default. So you should add this to your xml file.

Comment: Yes, I know sir but I do not know hot to do that.

Comment: Now i wrote in my manifest under activity Menu3 android:theme="@style/AppTheme" (there is the NavBar)

Comment: @Alan sorry I can not post code with action bar(I use phone to answer), but it should be something like that:
https://github.com/sabal202/Dumpy_Lyceum/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: @VailaSergeev LOL solved it! I forget the nclude tag! I vote you up thanks for our kindness! :D V